# Laravel continously check if there is a new item in an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I am fairly new to laravel and I want to implement a system in my projects that "alerts" users when there is a new comment on one of there posts.

I currently query all comments on the posts of the logged in user and put everything in an array and send it to my view. Now my goal is to make an alert icon or something when there is a new item in this array.

Is there an easy way to do this with some laravel helper function or something? I can't seem to find anything in the laravel documentation.

Is this even the right way to approach this?

Here's my code:

```
$uid = Auth::user()->id;
$projects = User::find($uid)->projects;
//comments
if (!empty($projects)) {
            foreach ($projects as $project) {
                    $comments_collection[] = $project->comments;
                }
            }

            if (!empty($comments_collection)) {
                $comments = array_collapse($comments_collection);

                foreach($comments as $com)
                {   
                    if ($com->from_user != Auth::user()->id) {
                        $ofdate = $com->created_at;
                        $commentdate = date("d M", strtotime($ofdate));
                        $comarr[] = array(
                                          'date' => $ofdate,
                                          $commentdate,User::find($com->from_user)->name,
                                          User::find($com->from_user)->email,
                                          Project::find($com->on_projects)->title,
                                          $com->on_projects,
                                          $com->body,
                                          Project::find($com->on_projects)->file_name,
                                          User::find($com->from_user)->file_name
                                         );
                    }    
                }
} else {
                $comarr = "";
}
```

If anyone can set me on the right way to reach my goal I would be very thankful! :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is an [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers).

So observer will watch Comment model, and in observer handler check the post and get user id and send notification or any other step you need to carry out.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to reach your goal.

1- the solution of [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers) in laravel , that will allow automatic execution of your script and getting notifications of changes.

2- by using an AJAX system to get new results by reloading variables